# What is the latest verified research on the 3x+1 Problem?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

[Wikipedia : Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

Take any positive integer n. If n is even, divide it by $2$ to get $n / 2$. If n is odd, multiply it by $3$ and add $1$ to obtain $3n + 1$. Repeat the process (which has been called "Half Or Triple Plus One", or HOTPO) indefinitely. The conjecture is that no matter what number you start with, you will always eventually reach $1$.

To quote:

> Steiner (1977) proved that there is no 1-cycle other than
> the trivial (1;2). Simons (2004) used Steiner's method to prove that
> there is no 2-cycle. Simons & de Weger (2003) extended this proof up
> to 68-cycles: there is no k-cycle up to k = 68. Beyond 68, this method
> gives upper bounds for the elements in such a cycle: for example, if
> there is a 75-cycle, then at least one element of the cycle is less
> than $2385\times 2^{50}$.

Has there been any legitimate progress since then, in terms of cycles or anything else?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If you are sure, then should we close this question?

Comment: Jeffrey Lagarias has two annotated bibliographies on the Collatz conjecture, for those who are too lazy to search for this research themselves, like the OP. They can be found on the arXiv, and describe hundreds of research papers on this conjecture.

Comment: @Parcly I assume you're being sarcastic.

Comment: @TMM I know, right? But I sincerely do think that while this conjecture is interesting, it's less important than (say) Riemann or lonely runner.

Comment: @Parcly Although the answer to the conjecture may be completely useless, such reasons have never stopped mathematicians to spend their time doing such research. And in the end, techniques used to prove/disprove the Collatz conjecture may turn out to be useful in other problems too.

Comment: @TMM But there are no published papers after 2010 in his bibliographies https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608208  Maybe you should do the research yourself.

Comment: @Yuval Those bibliographies show how much research has been done in several decades, and that was my point. Do you really think the absence of a new annotated bibliography means research stopped? It just means you will have to do further searching yourself if you insist on finding even more recent research. (And I'm not sure if you're really that stupid, but saying "maybe you should do the research yourself" certainly is. *You* want to know if more recent research exists, not me. I tell you yes and it is not hard to find it, and you complain I'm not handing it to you on a silver platter.)

Comment: "Maybe you should do the research yourself."  I was on the fence about leaving this open (in review), but you've dissuaded me.

Answer (score 4):

Fields Medalist Tao has a blog post on [The Collatz conjecture, Littlewood-Offord theory, and powers of 2 and 3](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/) from August 25, 2011.

Quoting Tao:

> "Needless to say, I didn’t solve the problem, but I have a better appreciation of why the conjecture is (a) plausible, and (b) unlikely be proven by current technology, and I thought I would share what I had found out here on this blog."

Comment: Interesting, but I still would like to see further developments.